# jQuery multiple conditions within if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the syntax for this loop to skip over certain keys?  The way I have it written is not working properly.

```
 $.each(element, function(i, element_detail){
    if (!(i == 'InvKey' && i == 'PostDate')) {
        var detail = element_detail + '&nbsp;';
        $('#showdata').append('<div class="field">' + i + detail + '</div>');
       }
 });
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: `if(i == 'InvKey' || i == 'PostDate'){`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

```
if (!(i == 'InvKey' || i == 'PostDate')) {
```

or

```
if (i != 'InvKey' || i != 'PostDate') {
```

that says if i does not equals `InvKey` OR `PostDate`

Comment: "If `i` does not equal 'InvKey' or 'PostDate'".

Answer (score 14):

`i == 'InvKey' && i == 'PostDate'` will never be true, since `i` can never equal two different things at once.

You're probably trying to write

```
if (i !== 'InvKey' && i !== 'PostDate'))
```

Comment: @Vega#1: Exactly.  And therefore it won't do what he wants.

Comment: and if they're elements he probably wants `$(element_detail).text()`

Comment: @SLaks `i` could be such string if element is an object not array.

Comment: From the same docs -> `$.each(map, function(key, value) {   alert(key + ': ' + value); });` - What if he is iterating a object

Answer (score 0):

**A more general approach:**

```
if ( ($("body").hasClass("homepage") || $("body").hasClass("contact")) && (theLanguage == 'en-gb') )   {

       // Do something

}
```